# Solr Plugin Development - API Backward Compatibility

Tags: java, git, solr, lucene

Folks, I am in the process of releasing a **plugin for Solr** (under ASF license) that implement different ranking strategies. I have tested it against 3.5 version, it works great, since I started fairly recently on open sourcing it went with latest version of Solr (3.5). But then a request came in to use that plugin for version 1.4. The problem is that Solr API has undergone some significant changes between 1.4 & 3.5.

For instance, SolrQueryResponse was moved from

```
org.apache.solr.REQUEST.SolrQueryResponse (1.4) 
to 
org.apache.solr.RESPONSE.SolrQueryResponse (3.5)
```

I use **Git** for DVCS, **Maven** for Build/Project Management, **Google Code** for project hosting, what would be an ideal strategy to make changes & maintain the code for different versions of underlying Solr/Lucene API. Branch could be way to achieve it, but I am not really convinced.

Would like to know if there is a better way to develop/maintain code for different underlying API versions & distribute them ?